# Can I deduct 529 college savings plan contribution from California income tax as a gift?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, california, state-income-tax, 529-plan

When I contribute to a 529 college savings plan, can I deduct the contribution from my California income tax as part of the gift tax exclusion (up to $15000)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 529 contributions are [not tax-deductible in California](https://www.merrilledge.com/ask/college/tax-advantages-of-california-529-plans). The Gift Tax exclusion isn't really appropriate, either, because gifts are after-tax anyway. Gift Taxes are extra taxes the giver pays beyond the exclusion amount.

Comment: Really the key point is that the "gift tax exclusion" does *not* relate to a *deduction from income*.